# Laravel Filesystem - Move file from one disk to another

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to move files from my FTP server to a local directory. First I need to find the correct file from the FTP server, as there can be a few hundreds:

```
//Search for the file.
$fileName= array_filter(Storage::disk('ftp')->files(), function ($file)
{
   return preg_match('/('.date("Y-m-d" ,time()).').*.XLSX/', $file);
});
```

Above finds the correct file. If I `dd($fileName)`, I get this: 
`My File Name.XLSX`

I then try to move that file, to my public disk:

```
 $ftp_file = Storage::disk('ftp')->get($fileName);
 $local_file = Storage::disk('public')->move($ftp_file, "moved_file.xlsx");
```

However above code doesn't work. I get below error:

> **preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given**

Which I have identified being on below function:

```
$ftp_file = Storage::disk('ftp')->get($fileName);
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I move the file, which I am able to find on my FTP server, to my local disk?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does [`array_filter`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) return? (hint: the filtered array).

Comment: @Loek - if I just `print_r(array_filter(...` it returns: `Array ( [0] => My File Name.XLSX )`

Comment: Which is an array, right? Anyway, `$fileName` contains an array and you're putting it into the `->get()` function which expects a string. Simply changing the parameter to `$fileName[0]` will solve your problem in this case.

Comment: @Loek, so I guess I have to use: `->get($fileName[0])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Loek pointed out, `$fileName` was an array, and therefore to access it I needed to use:

```
 $ftp_file = Storage::disk('ftp')->get($fileName[0]);
```